# If nucleons are tied together are their quarks closer with each other than in the single nucleon?

Tags: nuclear-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, subatomic

If the volume of the core of an atom is the sum of the volumes of every single nucleon does this mean that quarks of two neighbouring neutrons are much closer than the quarks in each of the two neutrons?

Answer (score 0):

Nucleons and their quarks are in the quantum mechanical framework where the adjective "close" has little meaning, because quantum mechanics depends on probabilities, i.e. probable locations.

Approximate values can be given , from scattering experiments,|

> [The size (diameter) of the nucleus](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_nucleus) is between 1.6 fm ($10^{−15}$ m) (for a proton in light hydrogen) to about 15 fm (for the heaviest atoms, such as uranium).

So even in a simplified model, your "If the volume of the core of an atom is the sum of the volumes of every single nucleon" is wrong. There is only a factor of 10 between largest and smallest effective volume measured, but the higher nuclei have a factor of more then 100 nuclei than the hydrogen atom.

This is because of the attractive forces that hold the nucleus together in its quantum mechanical form.

As for quarks, they are tightly bound within each nucleus and it is only the [spill over forces](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction#Nuclear_force) of the [strong force](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction#Colour_strong_force), that creates the attractive nuclear force.

Comment: In that case about 250 nucleons in Uraníum have 1000x more volume than Hydrogen proton?

Comment: Does it imply there are distances between nucleons?

Comment: Everything is probabilstic and quantum mechanical. In fermi , given in my answer , no. You keep doing classical comutations for quantum states. the numbers come from scattering.

Comment: $(15/1.6)^3\approx824$